# Get position of character in a string inside "for of" loop

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to get the position of a character in a string if its been separated programatically for example in a for of loop? So if I wanted to print to console the position of each character in a string with this loop
 i.e.

```
for (let c of myString) {
  console.log(c[some method to get index of c]);
}
```

I understand that using a "regular" for loop where we track an integer iterator would work if I just printed the iterator.  Just wondering if there's a way to track this using the for of syntax. `myString.indexOf(c)` is not a valid solution since it could easily return an incorrect position.

Comment: No, not without modifying code outside that loop body.

Comment: ok thanks, I was hoping there was some sort of elegant method like get char position from parent, but it makes sense that it's not possible.

Comment: Arent you just asking for iterator?

Comment: You could alternatively use your own iterator: `function* iter(str) {
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) yield [str[i], i];
}
for (let [c, i] of iter("abc")) console.log(c, i);`

Comment: Interesting, though more complicated and less readable than a regular `for(let i = 0; i < myString.length;++i)` though you did still answer the question.

Comment: As others have mentioned `for` doesn't give an index. `forEach` does though, so this works: `Array.from(myString).forEach((i, index) => console.log(i, index))`

Answer (score 2):

You can sure do it using `destructuring` and `Array.prototype.entries()`

```
for (let [index, value] of myString.split('').entries()) {
    console.log(index, value);
}
```

Performance and suitability of this code block to be considered per use case.

Comment: Interesting, I like it, I often find that Array has more features than String.